# Hard Drive Space Missing

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive

After creating a restore partition on my external hard drive, I noticed that it had wiped everything, created a new Restore partition that was a whole 30 gigs, after I created a 500 MB Partition, prior to the latter, because there was a message that mentioned the partition would only need 250 MB (I must have misunderstood that).

I deleted the 30 GB Restore Partition and tried to extend my initial volume that had been wiped, upon this attempt I received a message stating that the object does not support the operation.

So what I did instead was deleted the Initial Volume and Extended the 'so-called' Restore partition that was now Not Allocated.

I formatted it (NTFS) and added the initial volume as the extension source.

I am now stuck with only 930 GB from An external hard drive that is 1TB in actual size.

Comment: What you describe is normal behavior.  You are not actually missing any space.  A mechanical HDD cannot decrease in size.

Comment: I understand that but my question is, where did all my space go to because my HDD was 990 something in space before this whole incident occured

Comment: 990 GB before or after the format which assigns a filesystem.  I am not sure what to say, there is absolutely no chance a 1 TB drive would have been 990 GB with a filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

NTFS always formats a 1TB disk to 931GB of usuable storage. Always. The reason is that hardware manufacturers consider a terabyte to be exactly 1000^4 bits, but a computer considers a terabyte to be 1024^4 bits.

```
1000^4 = 1000000000000
1024^4 = 1099511627776
```

see here for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TiB

So, short answer, what you are seeing is normal and expected, and you haven't lost anything, because whether you noticed it or not, before your partitioning debacle, the initial size was 930-931GiB.

Comment: Windows will always use base 2 to display bytes.  OS X can be configured to display bytes in base 2 or base 10.  1000^2 = base 10 1024^2 = base 2.

Comment: wow. They probably want to bring back EBCIDIC cause they think its ironic.

Comment: Apple changed the way it displays a byte all the way back in 10.6.  I suppose Microsoft focused on more "important" things like the Modern UI in 2009.

Comment: The difference comes from the fact manufacture of storage device advertise a rounded size in one base and OS manufacture displays the actual size in another base.  I am not sure IEC notation applies (to this case)..

Comment: Thanks Guys, In that case, I guess I'm just having my own misconceptions with regards to my HDD space.